# How to get data from table with no matching column?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been bumping my head over trying to find the perfect query that will allow me to display the first and last names of all people involved in a conversation about a specific project.

**conversations table**

```
convo_id | project_id | toEmployee_id | fromEmployee_id | message
```

**employees**

```
employee_id | first_name | last_name |
```

**myinbox.php**

```
SELECT * FROM projects as p
JOIN employeeprojects AS ep
ON p.project_id = ep.project_id
JOIN employees AS e
ON ep.assigned_by = e.employee_id
JOIN clients AS c
ON p.client_id = c.id
WHERE ep.employee_id='$session_myemployeeid'

<a data-toggle="tooltip" title="view conversation"  href='conversation_feed.php?viewproject=conversation&emprojectid=<?=$employeeproject['project_id'];?>View Conversation</a>
```

**displayconversation.php**

```
$projectconvoid =  $_GET['emprojectid'] ;
SELECT * FROM employeeprojects_conversation AS epc
JOIN projects AS p
ON epc.project_id=p.project_id
JOIN employeeprojects AS ep
ON p.project_id=ep.project_id
WHERE epc.project_id='$projectconvoid'
```

While it all work great at displaying specific project conversation with the people involved, I would like to be able to display their name rather their `employee_id`.

How can I do that?

Comment: join the employees table. And indent your SQL

Comment: Like you did with previous query, `JOIN employees AS e
ON ep.assigned_by = e.employee_id`

Comment: @chris85: yes I thoguht so. The thing with this query FROM and TO display the names of the employee who assigned_the_project.

Comment: What is `FROM` and `TO`?

Comment: @chris85: On the conversation table it shows FROM John TO John with your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

join `employees` table twice, one for `toEmployee_id` and one for `fromEmployee_id` like so:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    employeeprojects_conversation AS epc
JOIN projects AS p
    ON epc.project_id=p.project_id
JOIN employeeprojects AS ep
    ON p.project_id=ep.project_id
JOIN employees AS emp
    ON emp.employee_id = epc.toEmployee_id
JOIN employees AS emp2
    ON emp2.employee_id = epc.fromEmployee_id
WHERE
    epc.project_id='$projectconvoid'
```

Comment: I was not sure I could do this without violating any rule. So while this works in phpmyadmin, in my application the same names display.

Comment: Logically the program will not know who to print since there are columns name duplicate right. But your query is good.

Comment: I give it to you because your query is good. However I decided to drop part of the php code and only display from who it is as I assume they will know it is for them.